# CSS table scrollable with minimum width items

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have made a table that has a fixed number of columns (5), a title for each column (a fixed row) and a dynamic number of rows.

When I try to make my app responsive, I want the `span`'s or items of each row to have a `min-width` (the same for all) and to be able to scroll horizontally while the parent `div` keeps the same width as the rest of the page.

If I try `span { min-width: 100px }` it makes the parent `div` expand with the rest of the page, even if I fix its maximum width it `div { max-width: 100% }`, and remain unscrollable. I have tried many combinations of `min-width`, `width`, `max-width` and none seems to make it responsive. Any way to make it work with this design?

HTML:

```
<div class="component-table">
  <div class="component-row-title">
    <span class="component-item-title"></span>
    <span class="component-item-title"></span>
    <span class="component-item-title"></span>
    <span class="component-item-title"></span>
    <span class="component-item-title"></span>
  </div>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index" class="component-row">
    <span class="component-item"></span>
    <span class="component-item"></span>
    <span class="component-item"></span>
    <span class="component-item"></span>
    <span class="component-item"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="another-component">
  ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.component-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.component-row-title {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000000;
}

.component-item-title {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.component-row {
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  font-size: 16px;
}

.component-row:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000000;
}

.component-item {
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make table scrollable, you should add **overflow: auto** to **.component-table**.
Also, to set min size of cell, you can update this code:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(var(--min-cell-width, 100px), 1fr));
```

which means: "create 5 columns with min size of **--min-cell-width** width, or 100px if not exist, and max 1fr".

To make border of each row to full width, we should use **fit-content**:

```css
width: fit-content;
```

Take a look on Code snippet for more details. I've added comments into CSS part.

```css
:root {
  --min-cell-width: 200px; /* css var for min cell width */
}

.component-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto; /* make table scrollable */
}

.component-row-title,
.component-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(var(--min-cell-width, 100px), 1fr)); /* 5 columns with css varible size; 100px - fallback size */
  width: fit-content; /* set row width to effect on border size */
}

.component-row-title {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000000;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.component-row {
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.component-row:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000000;
}

.component-item-title,
.component-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="component-table">
  <div class="component-row-title">
    <span class="component-item-title">t1</span>
    <span class="component-item-title">t2</span>
    <span class="component-item-title">t3</span>
    <span class="component-item-title">t4</span>
    <span class="component-item-title">t5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="component-row">
    <span class="component-item">1</span>
    <span class="component-item">2</span>
    <span class="component-item">3</span>
    <span class="component-item">4</span>
    <span class="component-item">5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="component-row">
    <span class="component-item">1</span>
    <span class="component-item">2</span>
    <span class="component-item">3</span>
    <span class="component-item">4</span>
    <span class="component-item">5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="component-row">
    <span class="component-item">1</span>
    <span class="component-item">2</span>
    <span class="component-item">3</span>
    <span class="component-item">4</span>
    <span class="component-item">5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="another-component">
  ...
</div>
```